# Showing Calcul result in Dialog (Android)

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

It's been days I'm trying to do something which seems simple but isn't.
In the application I'm making, a method calculates a value and is supposed to show the result in a dialog when you click on the button. However, every time I click on the Result button, the result is 0 because it's the number's initial value. Have you got a solution ?

Here is the method :

```
public int Calcul(int number){
if(position == 0 && state1){
    number=number+1;}
else{
    number=number+4;}
return number; }
```

And Here is the Dialog :

```
public void Result(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title")
           .setMessage("Result : " + Integer.toString(number))
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   }
               });

    builder.show();
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you post the whole code? It will give a clear idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should create the `Dialog` from `AlertDialog.Builder` object first then show the `Dialog` as follows...

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog .show();
```

And, the main thing, you are passing only `number` through the `Integer.toString()` where you should pass the returned result by calling `Calcul()` inside the `toString()` method.

So, you updated code snippet will be...

```
public void Result(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title")
           .setMessage("Result : " + Integer.toString(Calcul(number)))
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   }
               });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog .show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
.setMessage("Result : " + Integer.toString(number))
```

with this

```
.setMessage("Result : " + Integer.toString(Calcul(number)))
```